# How to use CSS grid framework for custom widths and gutters?

Tags: css, xhtml, blueprint-css, css-frameworks, 960.gs

How to make custom [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) grid framework for custom widths? In my company i get design (PSD) in different sizes in width site like 900px, 920 px, 915px, 973 px etc. and different gutter sizes like 10 px on right, 20 px on left etc. in this type of condition how can i use and take benefir of grid based framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everybody seems to have missed the point: if your gutters are not regular, then you can't use a grid system. You just create custom classes for each column and use them as needed. The grid systems use regular gutters so you can stack them (the columns) in a any order you like.

-- Jason

Answer (score 5):

http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/

This will generate the CSS based on the values defined in the form.

Comment: u didn't get my question .I mean in grid framework we use fixed width or gutter and spacing between items

Comment: In my company i get design (PSD) in different sizes in width site like 900px, 920 px, 915px, 973 px etc. and different gutter sizes like 10 px on right, 20 px on left etc. in this type of condition how can i use and take benefir of grid based framework

Comment: So maybe you could rephrase your question so that we understand what kind of answer you are expecting?!

Comment: We can only use if we yourself make design (according to proportions) if we are not designer of PSD then in most cases we can't use CSS grid based framework.?

Comment: Did you go to Squid's link, Jitendra? It will make grid based on whatever your PSD dimensions are.

Comment: Also, this is really more of a workflow issue. Visual Design and Production can't exist in separate vacuums. If it make sense to use a CSS grid, the visual designers should be incorporating that into their methodology.

Answer (score 1):

[The 960 generator](http://www.spry-soft.com/grids/) ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use http://www.960.gs. There are a number of online options to create a grid system. Its pretty simple!

Answer (score 0):

If your widths and gutters are arbitrary sizes, you can't use one grid system for them all.

To create a different grid system for each design, there needs to be a common divisor between the widths - which is what the link provided by dr.squid does - but with widths such as 973, you'll struggle.

Comment: thx u got my question in this type of condition can we mke custom reusable css grid framework?